# m2e in Eclipse Indigo no longer working

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse, eclipse-indigo

m2e is no longer working in my Eclipse Indigo. Nothing is printed to the Maven console, I can't download any sources and some dependencies won't be resolved.
I'm using the embedded Maven installation.

Do you know how to fix this issue?

Comment: You need to be more specific.  Any errors in the error log?  Was it working before?  What version of m2e are you using?

Comment: No errors in the log. It seems that the console never works when Maven is installed afterwards. I'm using the newest version of m2e. All other things have been working before.

Comment: I have the same, all works fine, but maven console view is always empty, even if debug checkbox in settings and debug output button in console view toolbar enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Just a wild guess (due to similar problems I had in the past):

- If you use the embedded m2e Maven installation, Maven has no information to your settings.
- If you are in a corporate environment, you have to set your proxy in a Maven related location:

  - In your users `settings.xml` file.
  - In your Maven installation `settings.xml` file

m2e can only use the proxy set in your Maven settings file, not the one in your eclipse environment. So as a result, you could see all the old libraries contained in local repositories, but no new ones contained only in remote repositories located somewhere on the internet.

Please add some more information about your configuration in eclipse (does eclipse find your user `settings.xml` file?) and the errors you get.

Answer (score 1):

Try -clean workspace option. Or if it doesn't help, create new workspace, test if m2e started working and import your old projects. I just resolved issue very similar to yours using second option.

Here is good explanation of such kind of troubles: http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t61566.html